# How to vertical align inline mathjax equation?

Tags: css, mathjax

As you could see on the image below, my inline MathJax equations are not well vertically aligned with the text baseline. If you look carefully, you will see that equations are lower than the text. May be 1 or two pixels.

[image]

I tried 3 browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Safari). Always the same problem.

All is perfect when I print a PDF from my browser.

I managed the inline equations font-size for MathJax with a simple CSS rule. That's right for this.

Equations are in a simple `<p>` or `<span>` tag.

Now, I only search a way to avoid this bad baseline alignment...

Can you help please?

EDIT : for the moment, my CSS is this :

```
.MathJax {
    font-size: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code. But you could manually correct the baseline by setting a negative `margin-top` on the `<p>` or `<span>` tags.

Comment: "margin-top" was a great idea. But no effects. Even with a -100px value. May be because it's an inline element.

Comment: In that case, maybe try `transform: translateY();` with a negative value, that should work even with inline elements.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm ok with this one "position: relative; top: -1px;". You are very nice to help!